# How to display images in Markdown files on Github?

Tags: github, markdown

I want to display some images in a Markdown file on Github. I found it works this way:

```
![Figure 1-1](https://raw.github.com/username/repo/master/images/figure 1-1.png "Figure 1-1")
```

But i need to collaborate with others so i don't want the username and repo name hard coded .

I tried to use this:

```
![Figure 1-1](images/figure 1-1.png "Figure 1-1")
```

It works on my local disk but not work on Github.

Is there anyone knows about this issue?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

Just simply append **?raw=true** to the image url will make the trick:

```
![](images/table 1-1.png?raw=true)
```

Comment: This works for me when viewing the Markdown files directly on GitHub, but not for the README.markdown file displayed on the project's main page.

Comment: @jmohr I think README files on the main page should be treated as an exception.

Comment: This worked on the README file on the main page for me.

Comment: Github still doesn't allow SVG even with `raw`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808020/include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown

Answer (score 30):

I just had the same issue and it turned out to be caused by the space in the URL. Manually URL encoding the space as `%20` fixed it.

So using your example I changed:

```
![](images/table 1-1.png)
```

to:

```
![](images/table%201-1.png)
```

2021 Edit: Thanks Emilio for pointing out that the GitHub flavored markdown spec has been updated to allow spaces in filenames when the filename is enclosed inside "pointy" (angle) brackets:

```
The destination can only contain spaces if it is enclosed in pointy brackets
Example 498
[link](</my uri>) --> <p><a href="/my%20uri">link</a></p>
```

Ref: https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-498 (scroll up for description)

This works with images too so we can now also use:

```
![](<images/table 1-1.png>)
```

Comment: They must've changed the spec since then because it now allows spaces if enclosed in pointy brackets. https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-497