# Include an SVG (hosted on GitHub) in MarkDown

Tags: svg, github, markdown

I know that an image can be placed in an MD with the MD syntax of either `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)` or `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Optional title")`, but I am having difficulty placing an SVG in MD where the code is hosted on GitHub.

Ultimately using rails3, and changing the model frequently right now, so I am using [RailRoady](https://github.com/preston/railroady) to generate an SVG of the schema diagram of the models.  I would like for that SVG to then be placed in the ReadMe.md, and be displayed.  When I open the SVG file locally, it does work, so how do I get the browser to render the SVG in the MD file?  Given that the code will be dynamic until it is finalized (seemingly never), hosting the SVG in a separate place seems overkill and that I am missing an approach to accomplish this.

The SVG I am trying to include is [here](https://github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/blob/master/doc/models_brief.svg) on GitHub: `https://github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/blob/master/Rails/fdxcm/doc/models_brief.svg`

I have tried the following, with an actual image as well to verify the syntax is working, just that the SVG code isn't being rendered:

```
![Overview][1]
[1]: https://github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/blob/master/doc/controllers_brief.svg  "Overview"

<img src="https://raw.github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/master/doc/controllers_brief.svg">

![Alt text](https://raw.github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/master/doc/controllers_brief.svg)

[Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1B95ajItJTAImL2WXISX0fkBLYk3nldea4Vm9eo-VyE4/edit) :

<img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/pub?id=117XsJ1kDyaY-n8AdPS3_8jTgMyITqaoT3-ah_BSc9YQ&w=960&h=720">

<img src="https://raw.github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/master/doc/controllers_brief.svg">

<img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1B95ajItJTAImL2WXISX0fkBLYk3nldea4Vm9eo-VyE4/edit">
```

to get the results of:

[image: Overview]
[1](https://github.com/preston/railroady): https://github.com/specialorange/FDXCM/blob/master/Rails/fdxcm/doc/controllers_brief.svg  "Overview"

[image]

[image]

---

[Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1B95ajItJTAImL2WXISX0fkBLYk3nldea4Vm9eo-VyE4/edit) :

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: GitHub now has a relevant open bug report: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/556

Comment: To save people the click, the bug report on github was opened on Oct 13, 2015.

Comment: Since Jan. 2022, it is supported in markdown files: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869502/6309).

Answer (score 271):

The purpose of `raw.github.com` is to allow users to view the contents of a file, so for text based files this means (for certain content types) you can get the wrong headers and things break in the browser.

When this question was asked (in 2012) SVGs didn't work. Since then Github has implemented various improvements. Now (at least for SVG), the correct Content-Type headers are sent.

The easiest way to add SVG is to use the [upload assets feature](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#uploading-assets). To quote the manual:

> You can upload assets like images by dragging and dropping, selecting from a file browser, or pasting. You can upload assets to issues, pull requests, comments, and .md files in your repository.

Since 2022, "images" also includes SVG:

[image: screenshot animation of SVG file upload]

---

Some comments regarding changes that happened along the way:

- Github has implemented a feature which makes it possible for SVG's to be used with the Markdown image syntax. The SVG image will be sanitized and displayed with the correct HTTP header. Certain tags (like `<script>`) are removed.

  To view the sanitized SVG or to achieve this effect from other places (i.e. from markdown files not hosted in repos on http://github.com/) simply append `?sanitize=true` to the SVG's raw URL.
- *As stated by [AdamKatz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519360/) in the comments, using a source other than github.io can introduce potentially privacy and security risks. See the [answer by CiroSantilli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606546/153049) and [the answer by DavidChambers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21521184/153049) for more details.*
- *[The issue to resolve this](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/556) was opened on Github on October 13th 2015 and was resolved on August 31th 2017*
- *Support for SVG drag-and-drop file upload was [announced January 21 2022](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-21-allow-to-upload-svg-files-to-markdown/)*

### Examples

All of the ways stated below will work.

<sup>I copied the SVG image from the question to [a repo on github](https://github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow) in order to create the examples below</sup>

### Linking to files using relative paths (Works, but obviously only on github.com / github.io)

**Code**

```
![Alt text](./controllers_brief.svg)
<img src="./controllers_brief.svg">
```

**Result**

See [the working example on github.com](https://github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow/blob/master/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/readme.md).

### Linking to RAW files

**Code**

```
![Alt text](https://raw.github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow/master/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg)
<img src="https://raw.github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow/master/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg">
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

### Linking to RAW files using `?sanitize=true`

**Code**

```
![Alt text](https://raw.github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow/master/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg?sanitize=true)
<img src="https://raw.github.com/potherca-blog/StackOverflow/master/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg?sanitize=true">
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

### Linking to files hosted on [github.io](http://github.io)

**Code**

```
![Alt text](https://potherca-blog.github.io/StackOverflow/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg)
<img src="https://potherca-blog.github.io/StackOverflow/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/controllers_brief.svg">
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying that the SVG images *won't* render, correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR No, everything but hotlinking the raw.github.com file  works fine. I had just renamed something in the github repo and forgot to update my answer, breaking the examples. Fixed now.

Comment: Oh I see.. thanks. And what about the other option of [linking to the svg file using a relative path, that you mention in your repo](https://github.com/potherca/StackOverflow/tree/gh-pages/question.13808020.include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown) ? I guess that doesn't work either. Probably the issue is with the github server, which sends svgs as text/plain. Is that correct?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Correct. Github never ment the raw view to be used as a way of hosting files, only for viewing, hence it sends a `text/plain` header.

Comment: Warning: rawgit.com and rawgithub.com are *not* owned or operated by GitHub, which introduces privacy and even security risks from abuse, if not from its current owner then perhaps from a future owner if the DNS registration lapses.  **This makes the github.io solution the safest.** See also [@CiroSantilli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606546/519360) and [@davidchambers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21521184/519360) which both note an [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) risk that this creates.

Comment: @AdamKatz Good point. I'll add a note to my answer stating these issues.

Comment: Important! RawGit does not work for private repos:
https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/62

Comment: @MonsieurDart I added your concern to the answer.

Comment: Thats nice but because it is rendered as `<img src=....` none of the links work in the svg. Svg rendered as `<svg>....</svg>` will work. Maybe there is a security risk in rendering svg as elements instead of using it as an img src property.

Comment: @HMR Although true, your statement has nothing to do with the original question of using Markdown to add an SVG image. The is no Markdown specific syntax to add an image inline, you just use the HTML `<svg>` tag instead.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, github could have a special markdown for svg so the links will work but I don't think they have it. SVG is now treated as an image and SVG i much more than an image so I imagine there will be risk involved.

Comment: In 2020 SVG images appear to render fine; see https://github.com/dspinellis/epidose. One issue I faced was failure to render an image that included a "&nbsp;" entity. I fixed it by adjusting the figure so as to avoid its generation.

Comment: Lovely. Would love to add that svgs created by different libraries work differently. Probably because of different XML header they use. for me `svgwrite` for python does not produce github-displayable svgs files while `drawSvg` for python works

Answer (score 49):

I contacted GitHub to say that github.io-hosted SVGs are no longer displayed in GitHub READMEs. I received this reply:

> We have had to disable svg image rendering on GitHub.com due to potential cross site scripting vulnerabilities.

Comment: Wait, does that happen? Didn't know.

Comment: Interestingly though, it does render on blob show: see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25606546/895245). So I can't understand why not in the README.

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 The blob uses an iframe which can't do XSS like an embedded SVG can.

Comment: Came here exactly searching if this was possible. Proof of concept that this is possible: https://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/krqea6gc/

Comment: Hm, click here to witness a XSS attack?  Nice.

Answer (score 23):

**Update 2020: how they made it work while avoiding [XSS attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important/72569#72569)**

GitHub appears to use two security approaches, this is a good article: https://digi.ninja/blog/svg_xss.php see also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/148507/how-to-prevent-xss-in-svg-file-upload

- show SVG inside `<img` tag, which prevents scripts from running, e.g. on READMEs: https://github.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/tree/8e394cdb012cba4bcf55ebdb89f36872b4c6c12a
- use `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox`. This prevents the script from running even in `raw` which contains the raw SVG file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cirosantilli/test-git-web-interface/8e394cdb012cba4bcf55ebdb89f36872b4c6c12a/svg-foreignObject.svg

  You can see the header with `curl -vvv`. The regular `github.com` pages also have a `content-security-policy`, but it is much larger.

**Update 2017**

A GitHub dev is currently looking into this: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/556#issuecomment-306103203

**Update 2014-12**: GitHub now renders SVG on blob show, so I don't see any reason why not to render on README renderings:

- https://github.com/blog/1902-svg-viewing-diffing
- https://github.com/cirosantilli/test/blob/2144a93333be144152e8b0d4144b77b211afce63/svg.svg

Also note that that SVG does have an XSS attempt but it does not run: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cirosantilli/test/2144a93333be144152e8b0d4144b77b211afce63/svg.svg

The billion laugh SVG does make Firefox 44 Freeze, but Chromium 48 is OK: https://github.com/cirosantilli/web-cheat/blob/master/svg-billion-laughs.svg

[Petah mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808020/include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown/25606546#comment57747518_21521184) that blobs are fine because the SVG is inside an `iframe`.

**Possible rationale for GitHub not serving SVG images**

- general XML vulnerabilities. E.g. opening a billion laughs exploit just made Firefox crash my system. Firefox bug with exploit attached: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=voting/user.html. Same on Chromium: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231562
- SVG XSS scripting: while most browsers don't run scripts when the SVG is embedded with `img`, it seems that this is not required by the standards, so maybe GitHub is playing it safe.

  Browsers do run it if you open the SVG directly (but it appears that GitHub never shows images directly on the `github.com` domain) or if it is inline (which are currently completely removed by GitHub), so those cases shouldn't be a security concern. Relevant links:

  - spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html
  - interactive SVG demo: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/script/script01.svg

The following questions asks about the risks of SVG in general: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/exploits-or-other-security-risks-with-svg-upload

Comment: Browsers don't run script when SVG is accessed via an image tag. Feel free to check yourself.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the correction. Is that specified on the standard, of just a common browser behavior? Is it done for security?

Comment: Its done for privacy, and it's not really in a standard. People understand how raster images work and what they can/can't do so when used as an image SVG images should work the same way.

Answer (score 16):

[rawgit.com](http://rawgit.com/) solves this problem nicely. For each request, it retrieves the appropriate document from GitHub and, crucially, serves it with the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: This is awesome! Must paste into the website? or can one just write the url dynamically via script for instance. I want to include this in my TextExpander snippet.

Comment: You needn't visit the website first, @GitSyncApp. :)

Comment: Are you sure? I tried something i've never pated into the webpage and it worked! This is super relevant these days,as DropBox is closing their public  folder support.

Comment: Perhaps you misread "needn't" as "need to", @GitSyncApp? It seems we agree. :)

Comment:  Totally misread that yes.  Super awesome!!! Hopefully this service doesn't buckle under the coming wave of DropBox public folder converts. Know any place to store .mp4 btw? For demo videos in markdown articles via Jekyll static sites on github.

Comment: Service is down today :(

Comment: Answering to myself…  RawGit does not work for private repos:
https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/62

Comment: rawgit.com is going away. According to the website: "RawGit has reached the end of its useful life
October 8, 2018
RawGit is now in a sunset phase and will soon shut down. It's been a fun five years, but all things must end.

GitHub repositories that served content through RawGit within the last month will continue to be served until at least October of 2019. URLs for other repositories are no longer being served.

If you're currently using RawGit, please stop using it as soon as you can."

Comment: Also from the rawgit.com sunset announcement: "What you should use instead
The following free services offer fantastic alternatives to some or all of RawGit's functionality. You may like them even more than RawGit.

jsDelivr
GitHub Pages
CodeSandbox
unpkg"

Answer (score 14):

Since Jan. 2022, that seems possible (and easy):

> ### [Allow to upload .svg files to Markdown](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-21-allow-to-upload-svg-files-to-markdown/)
>
> It is now possible to upload `.svg` files to comments in issues, PRs, discussions, and Markdown files, like `READMEs`.
>
> You just have to drag and drop the file in the text area.
>
> [image: An animation showing how to upload a SVG image to an issue comment.]

Answer (score 9):

This will work. Link to your SVG using the following pattern:

`https://cdn.rawgit.com/<repo-owner>/<repo>/<branch>/path/to.svg`

The downside is hardcoding the owner and repo in the path, meaning the svg will break if either of those are renamed.

Comment: Another downside of using `cdn.rawgit.com` is that the "files are cached permanently based on the URL". It won't ever update if you modify the file, unless you change the name or path.

Comment: @Mottie: rawgit has update now: "New changes you push to GitHub will be reflected within minutes."

Comment: Important! RawGit does not work for private repos:
https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/62

Comment: Update 2018. rawgit is sunsetting. See my comment above.

Answer (score 6):

You can also insert [animated SVG images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) like any other format.
It can be a good alternative to GIF images.

```markdown
![image description](relative/path/in/repository/to/image.svg)
OR
<img src="relative/path/in/repository/to/image.svg" width="128"/>
```

Example (assuming the image is in `assets` directory in the repository):

```markdown
![My animated logo](assets/my-logo.svg)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I can get the .svg to display, but not the links embedded in it. For that, I had to paste the whole svg file's code instead of calling it with the code above.

Answer (score 5):

**Just like this worked for me on Github.**

```
![Image Caption](ImageAddressOnGitHub.svg)
```

or

```
<img src="ImageAddressOnGitHub.svg">
```

Comment: When this question was asked (in 2012) things were a lot more confusing. Luckily things _just work_ nowadays!

Answer (score 4):

I have a working example with an img-tag, but your images won't display.
The difference I see is the content-type.

I checked the github image from your post (the google doc images don't load at all because of connection failures). The image from github is delivered as content-type: text/plain, which won't get rendered as an image by your browser.

The correct content-type value for svg is image/svg+xml. So you have to make sure that svg files set the correct mime type, but that's a server issue.

Try it with http://svg.tutorial.aptico.de/grafik_svg/dummy3.svg and don't forget to specify width and height in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use this site: https://rawgit.com , it works for me as I don't have permission issue with the svg file.
Please pay attention that RawGit is not a service of github, as mentioned in [Rawgit FAQ](https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) :

> RawGit is not associated with GitHub in any way. Please don't contact GitHub asking for help with RawGit

Enter the url of svg you need, such as :

```
https://github.com/sel-fish/redis-experiments/blob/master/dat/memDistrib-jemalloc-4.0.3.svg
```

Then, you can get the url bellow which can be used to display:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/sel-fish/redis-experiments/master/dat/memDistrib-jemalloc-4.0.3.svg
```

Comment: Important! RawGit does not work for private repos:
https://github.com/rgrove/rawgit/issues/62