# Embed SVG image in GitHub wiki in 2016

Tags: svg, github, wiki

Yes, there are [questions about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808020/include-an-svg-hosted-on-github-in-markdown). Unfortunately, the answers are all messy now with information about different things that worked differently across the past five or so years.

So how the heck am I to

- embed
- an svg image
- in a GitHub .wiki folder
- inside a GitHub .wiki page

I can't believe you need a PhD for this.

Here is my example page with broken embedding:
- https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaCollider/wiki/Architecture/2413e094a59df4705e770b2a57ff84a8f0a1e7b4

Here is the actual thing:
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Sciss/ScalaCollider/images/ScalaCollider_types.svg

I suppose the problem is this renders as raw text instead of being shown as svg image?

And no, I don't want to set up gh-pages. I want to use the bloody Wiki, because that is what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so apparently this is what happens:

- GitHub doesn't want to render images properly from rawgithubcontent.
- So forget about embedding them in the wiki
- Create a gh-pages branch for the main project unless you already have one
- Find or create an unused directory in that branch, and add the image there
- Link to the gh-pages URL

E.g. https://sciss.github.io/ScalaCollider/images/ScalaCollider_types.svg

Not cool, but it works.

Comment: With a heavy heart, thanks for this answer. I'm looking forward to the day when it's no longer correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [jsdelivr.net](https://www.jsdelivr.com/).

**Steps**:

1. Upload the file `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Sciss/ScalaCollider/images/ScalaCollider_types.svg` to one folder under any repository.
2. Find the svg link on GitHub, and click to the "Raw" version.
3. Copy the URL.
4. Change `raw.githubusercontent.com` to `cdn.jsdelivr.net`
5. Insert `/gh/` before your username.
6. Remove the `branch` name.
7. (Optional) Insert the *version* you want to link to, as `@version` (if you do not do this, you will get the *latest* - which may cause long-term caching)
8. Using label `image`, then add `?sanitize=true` to the path tail of the svg file.

For example,

If raw svg file path in github is:

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yanglr/Beautify-cnblogs/master/images/github-pendant-rightCorner.svg`

You can use below:

```html
<a href="https://github.com/yanglr">
<img style="position: absolute; top: 76px; right: 0; border: 0" alt="Fork me on GitHub" 
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/yanglr/Beautify-cnblogs/images/github-pendant-rightCorner.svg?sanitize=true"></a>
```

The result:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)