# github svg not rendering at all

Tags: github, svg, markdown

I am trying to create a markdown file in GitHub and would like to put an SVG image in it. GitHub is not rendering the image at all. I tried with `<img />`, with `![]()`. Is simply not working!

Just modified the repository so that is public: https://github.com/michelucci/deepbook

Comment: Can you share a link ?

Comment: Sure... Just modified to be a public repository... https://github.com/michelucci/deepbook

Answer (score 1):

GitHub's markdown seems to be blocking SVG files, but you can always use bare HTML tags:

```
<img src="neuron_fig1.svg"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried (see the repository). But nothing is showing up!

Comment: @Umberto If you want to use fully qualified links instead of relative one, you need to use `raw.githubusercontent.com`, i.e.: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michelucci/deepbook/master/images/neuron_fig1.svg`.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried your solution above just pointing to the file itself but is not showing anything. I will try with a fully qualified link...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like GitHub now requires the http query parameters `sanitize=true` at the end of the SVG string. If you're linking to an image in your repository from a wiki, you may already have parameters at the end of the URL. So either add `?sanitize=true` if there are no query parameters, or `&sanitize=true` otherwise

```
<img alt="my image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/branch/images/myimage.svg?example=foo&sanitize=true>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022: [a simple drag & drop is enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70869502/6309).

---

Original answer (2017)

See [issue 458](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer/issues/458) regarding any inline HTML, but since it is not your issue, you can compare [your page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michelucci/deepbook/master/Structure%20of%20a%20neuron.ipynb) to [this one](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/libdynd/libdynd/blob/master/docs/intro-01/HowDyNDViewsMemory.ipynb): it does display a lot of svg pictures, and its [source is here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/libdynd/libdynd/master/docs/intro-01/HowDyNDViewsMemory.ipynb).

```
"source": [
    "## Python Objects\n",
    "\n",
    "We begin with a look at a Python object. In Python, objects are stored in memory blocks independently allocated on the heap. A single floating point value looks something like this:\n",
    "\n",
    "![Python Float](fig/python_float.svg)\n",
    "\n",
    "This doesn’t look too bad, in a dynamically typed system we need to store some metadata about the type, and we need to store the data containing the value."
   ]
  },
```

So relative URL (to [`docs/intro-01/fig`](https://github.com/libdynd/libdynd/tree/master/docs/intro-01/fig)) does work.

Your code:

```
   "source": [
    " ![](neuron_fig1.svg) \n",
    " **Fig. 1** The structure of a neuron. $x_i$ are the input, $w_i$ are the weights."
   ]
```

Comment: I believe you! But in my case is not showing anything... Maybe are how the svg are written. I generated them with inkscape...

Comment: @Umberto I have added your current code to compare against the example I have found working.

Comment: Thanks but ```![Python Float](fig/python_float.svg)``` is similar to my (note that I moved the image to my root directory to see if that would have helped) but still no luck... I don't see any difference (except that my is referring to an image in the same root directory)... Oh and by the way with png it works perfectly (I updated the files).

Comment: @Umberto I agree. All I see is tose extra spaces in your string.

Comment: To add to it, it woks perfectly on my laptop locally.

Comment: @Umberto can you try with the source code and svg picture of the example I have found? (when added, committed and pushed to your GitHub repo). Just for testing.

Comment: Have to leave now. Will try later. Thx!!

Comment: @Umberto if this works on your computer but not on GitHub, do check the eol (end of line) characters: make sure they are not changed on commit. `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: Tried that but not working... I probably have to use png. Altough it annoys me to admit defeat.

Comment: @Umberto did you check your end of lines? Both for your ipynb file, and your svg file?

Comment: Tried your command and did a new commit. Trying to check the end of lines for both. Need to figure out how to do it on github ;) But I tried to upload the files to another repository via web (I usually use desktop) and it did not work exactly as in my original repository...

Comment: @Umberto the command merely prevent any eol manipulation for *new* files. Try instead to create new files (with making sure of their eol), add, commit, and push

Comment: Tried. still not working. Will try a completely new repository and I will see how it goes. Will delete the old one

Comment: Ok I don't know. It possibly be sketch that export the images in some kind of wrong format, or something else, but I will move to png. Pity, but I don't think it is worth to waste more time on this. Thank you very much @VonC for all your help!!

Comment: I get this error (I checked the web errors from the console): Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/images/neuron_fig1.svg Quite strange... It works with png...