# How to embed SVG code inside jekyll markdown (on Github)?

Tags: svg, jekyll

Naively I thought it would be easy to just add `<svg>` tag with content in my post.md page, like this:

```
---
published: true
title: Embeded SVG
---
## title

<svg width="400" height=300>
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

But instead of the image being displayed, I see the SVG code displayed (in Firefox). So far did not found any solution to what looks like a simple thing. Is it possible within jekyll / liquid markdown ?

Note: I read [include an SVG (hosted on github) in MarkDown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13808020/51386), but:

- I want to manipulate the svg code with d3.js latter, so I am assuming that I need to embed the SVG code, not reference it as an external image file.
- I could generate the initial svg content directly with d3.js (this works), but this would prevent anything to be displayed in case javascript is disabled...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can [disable kramdown](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/quickref.html#extensions) specifically for your svg :

```
{::nomarkdown}
<svg width="400" height=300>
    <circle cx="150" cy="100" r="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
{:/}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! Do you know why markdown has to be disable for svg tag ?